# phpmailer umlauts wont show correctly

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, phpmailer

I have a little issue with the PHPMailer script.

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
        // Server settings
        //$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = ''; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = ''; // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = ''; // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to

        // Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('info@example.com', 'Störungsfall');
        $mail->addAddress('mail@example.com', 'name'); // Add a recipient

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Störungsmeldung für.. '. $suchtext .'.';
        $mail->Body = '

<html>
... html mail..
</html>

...
```

My umlauts wont show correctly. If I omit the CharSet, it looks like this:

[image: without charset UTF-8]

If I set the CharSet it looks like this:

[image: With CharSet set]

I tried to use `&ouml;` instead of `ö`, but it comes out 1:1 St`&ouml;`ungsfall in the header.

Here is the debug log, maybe it will help you more than me :(

```
2018-01-15 15:23:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: =?UTF-8?Q?St=F6rungsfall?= <info@example.com>
2018-01-15 15:23:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?St=F6rungsmeldung_f=FCr.._example.?=
```

Comment: Did you save this script file as UTF-8 …?

Comment: oh my gosh, i hate it... so simple solution and i try'd so much :(